# SearchBar rotation problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am sorry for images but I don't know better way to explain my problem.
This is view when I start application, all is fine.
[image]
This is when I rotate phone, search bar top part is now a little bit under navigation bar.
[image]
I start search and cancel it.
[image]
Now search bar is not covered with navigation bar, but navigation bar is smaller by height.
[image]
And when I go bac to vertical view, navigation bar is still small and I have a black hole under it.
[image]
And I can't find why this is happening, any help?

This is the code how I create and add search bar:

```
- (void) loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    sBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,45)];
    sBar.delegate = self;
    sBar.placeholder = @"Search";       
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = sBar;

    UISearchDisplayController *searchDC = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:sBar contentsController:self];

    self.searchDisplayController = searchDC;    

    searchDC.delegate = self;
    searchDC.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchDC.searchResultsDelegate = self;

    [sBar release];
    [searchDC release]; 
}
```

I didn't change anything in rotation methods specifically for navigation or search bar.

Comment: Images are ok, but we can't help without code/xib

Comment: I updated question with code how I add search bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify all your views frames in:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

And if they are not ok set the correct frame.

Comment: I didn't make it, but I fix it to work a little bit different. In 'shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation' method I add that whenever application comes to vertical/horizontal view change navigation bar size to its default. Satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution is to add `UISearchBar` to `UITableView` header. In this case all staff will be handled out of the box.

Setting frame can cause problems with UISearchBar width while switching between views and rotating. I experienced this issue in tab based app. Yeah, the test case is not so easy to reproduce, but stil it's a bug.